# How to show the dispersion operator is an orthogonal projection.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

[image]

How do you show that the dispersion operator is the projection map in this case. I tried, but I couldn't get the right result.

EDIT: Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this? The dispersion operator of $Y$ is defined to be  $Cov(Y,Y)$, just an fyi.